# How to call a COM function that returns a string when called from C#, Java

Tags: c#, c++, com, com-interop

Problem Statement:

1. Add a function to an existing COM library that returns a string.
2. C# application consumes the COM library using the COM interop version (.net runtime assembly generated using tblimp)

Till now, I've tried the following variations:

Code on C++ side:

Variation 1: `HRESULT GetString([out] BSTR* string);`

Variation 2: `HRESULT GetString([out,retval] BSTR* string);`

Code on C# side:

```
string str;
```

Variation 1: `GetString(out str);`

Variation 2: `str = GetString();`

However both raise `Attempt to read/write memory` or similar worded exception.

Am I on the right track? Or are there some marshalling limitations that cause the exception to be raised (like when doing memory management etc) ? I could not find a clear explanation on the net as to which approach will work best for the above scenario, so this call for help.

Going further the plan is also that this COM function will be called from a Java app.

Note: Please disregard function syntax, might contain errors. The implemented code in COM works without any issues when called from within C++ COM library for both variations but fails for C# as stated above.

Comment: Your C++ code is wrong, I can't see it from here.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not worried about syntax but the approach here.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect there is a problem in your C++ code.  Assuming you're using ATL, one approach to returning a string is to do this:

```
HRESULT GetString([out,retval] BSTR* string)
{
    const char* ReturnString = "A string to return";
    *string = CComBSTR( ReturnString ).Detach();
    return S_OK;
}
```

Where ReturnString can be replaced with whatever string you wish to return.

Comment: How is this function signature different from the variation [2] that I've mentioned above for C++ code? I'm doing allocation on the COM side with C# expected to free it.

Comment: The function signature isn't different, but I don't think the problem is in your function signature.  If you post your C++ code, then I or others may be able to tell you the exact problem.

Comment: I see your point. I've observed that the function works flawlessly when called from a COM library or using import of a dll in C#.

Comment: To add, the code too is similar to what you written above. I do not understand why is it that the same function causes an exception when called from interop? Should I be passing the string length and an allocated buffer from C# to write into by C++ so that memory management is made easier? I wish to avoid this approach since then the function can no longer return variable length strings.

Comment: I suspect that the function is failing from interop because you are allocating memory or similar slightly incorrectly in the C++ GetString function, which is causing problems when called from C#.  However, it probably works when called from C++ because nothing is automatically dealing with releasing & allocating memory, so you're not encountering issues.  I would not recommend passing an allocated buffer from C#, that sounds like a really bad solution to this problem.  But, I can't really help you anymore unless you edit your post to contain the C++ implementation of GetString.

Comment: Thanks obmarg.I identified the problem. It was a 32-bit, 64-bit issue. I've 2 versions of the COM library. The .NET side was executing in 64-bit. I was just replacing the 32-bit COM dll and testing it.The signature of the function in the 64-bit was incorrect. This was way back so I do not remember what syntax caused the issue but just thought of bringing this topic to a close. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You also asked about java...

You have to use JNI. You declare the functions as *native*, then generate the wrapping code and inside it you can access whatever you want, e.g. .NET libraries or COM.

Have a look here:
http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html